# Processing unhandled exceptions in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, blazor

In ASP.NET Core 3.1 a feature was added where unhandled exceptions can be passed onto an instance of ILogger as noted here:
[Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#log-errors-with-a-persistent-provider)

I have a Server side Blazor website where I want to be able to process these exceptions in a function where I can log them to a database or perhaps send an email.  However I am unable to come up with code to do this based on the provided documentation.  Could someone provide sample code to trap unhandled exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some playing around, I found a way to do error logging without having to use a third party tool.  Here is my code:

```
  public class ExceptionLogger : ILogger
  {
    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
      return null;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
      return logLevel == LogLevel.Error;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
      if (logLevel == LogLevel.Error)
      {
        while (exception.InnerException != null)
          exception = exception.InnerException;

        LogException(exception);
      }
    }

    private void LogException(Exception error)
    {
      ...
    }


  public sealed class ExceptionLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
  {

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
      return new ExceptionLogger();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
  }
```

And in Startup.cs add this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  loggerFactory.AddProvider(new ExceptionLoggerProvider());
  ...
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommand to use [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) with sinks you need.

In your project add packages :

```sh
dotnet add package Serilog.AspNetCore
dotnet add package Serilog.Settings.Configuration
dotnet add package Serilog.Sinks.Console
dotnet add package Serilog.Sinks.Debug
dotnet add package Serilog.Sinks.Seq
```

[Serilog.AspNetCore](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore) to integrate Serilog with ASP.Net core.
[Serilog.Settings.Configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration) to read serilog config from .Net core configuration.
[Serilog.Sinks.Console](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks) to write logs in the console.
[Serilog.Sinks.Debug](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-debug) to write logs in Visual Studio output pane.
[Serilog.Sinks.Seq](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-seq) to write logs  in a [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq) server, which is much more powerful than a DB.

Setup login in your *Program.cs* with :

```cs
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration))
        .Build();
```

And in Startup.cs:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Admin/Error");
    }

    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging()
```

And configure your logs in *appsettings.json* with:

```
"Serilog": {
    "LevelSwitches": {
      "$controlSwitch": "Information"
    },
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "ControlledBy": "$controlSwitch"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Seq",
        "Args": {
          "serverUrl": "http://localhost:5341/",
          "controlLevelSwitch": "$controlSwitch",
          "apiKey": "{SeqApiKey}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Debug"
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      "WithMachineName",
      "WithThreadId"
    ]
  }
```

This tell Serilog to use the log level configure in Seq for your app.

```
   "LevelSwitches": {
      "$controlSwitch": "Information"
    }
...
        "Args": {
          "serverUrl": "http://localhost:5341/",
          "controlLevelSwitch": "$controlSwitch",
          "apiKey": "{SeqApiKey}"
        }
```

`{SeqApiKey}` is an Api key configure in your Seq server for your app.

If you want to use a DB, Serilog has [long list of sinks](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks) you can use.

Comment: Hi @agua, what about NLog ?

Comment: Hi @daniherrera, actualy you can use NLog if you want, but I prefer Serilog.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it by yourself, on top of your middleware pipe add:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Admin/Error");
    }

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        try
        {
            await next().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            LogException(e);
            throw;
        }
    })
```

Comment: This will only catch errors in the http bases calls, ie in the startup phase. The SignalR connection doesn't pass through the middleware.

Comment: @HenkHolterman But SignalR errors are catched and logged, IMO : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: LOgged: yes. But it seems hard to catch them yourself: On [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1) there are a lot of try/catch at different places.

Comment: An UnhandledException event on Circuit or App level would seem nice. I'm not sure why we don't have that.

Comment: There already are some discussions going on there, I'll have to catch up first.

Comment: I did some testing by adding this code and then throwing an exception at a certain point in a razor file.  This did not catch that exception.