# Dependency Injection into an ILogger object

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor-server-side, ilogger

I have a Server side Blazor application where I am implementing an ILogger object to catch unhandled application errors and log them.  You can see how I did that in my answer here:
[Processing unhandled exceptions in ASP.NET Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413587/processing-unhandled-exceptions-in-asp-net-core-3-1/62091211#62091211)

What I would like to do is to use dependency injection to pass objects into my ILogger object so it can get more information to log about the exception.  But I am not able to figure out how to do that.  I tried adding DI objects to the constructor of the ExceptionLoggerProvider and ExceptionLogger objects, but I couldn't get that to work.  Can someone provide an example of how to do that?

For example, I have a LoginAccount DI class I created which tracks the logged in user which I setup like this which I would like to be injected into my ILogger object.

```
services.AddScoped<LoginAccount>();
```

Comment: Can you explain (and preferably show) what kinds of information you wish to provide, and where that information is coming from?

Comment: I don't understand why you disregarded the Serilog answer in the other question. Also adding this custom code inside a Logger seems sketchy and very error prone to me, especially when you refer to the `LoginAccount`. Either way Serilog is a really nice tool to have in your belt and very customizable if it doesn't cover you by default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the reference in startup.cs service object.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IDataAccess, DataAccess>();
}
```

Did you add that or you missed that?

Comment: I have Dependency Injection working elsewhere in the project. I just want to be able to have some of them injected into my ILogger object

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly, you can implement something like this-

Add `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` in `Program.cs`

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

If you are implementing in Model class, you can call something like this-

```
private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;

public class YourModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<YourModel> _logger;

    public YourModel(ILogger<YourModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

And you can call like this inside your Action/methods to log info. You can pass exception/event object as well.

```
_logger.LogInformation("Log your info here.");
```

If you are implementing in Controller, you can use something like -

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<YourController> _logger;

    public YourController(ILogger<YourController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
 }
```

And similar way you can call like this inside your Controller Actions to log info-

```
_logger.LogInformation("Log your info here");
```

To override the default set of logging providers added by `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`, call `ClearProviders` and add the required logging providers. For example, the following code in `Program.cs`:

```js
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddConsole();  //you can pass any third party logging provider here
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

For further info, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).